# Using latest postgres driver with gorm

Tags: go-gorm

I am using the gorm release v1.24.2, and I am using gorm.io/driver/postgres which is v1.4.5, and that version uses pgx v4.  Now I noticed github.com/go-gorm/postgres has been updated to use pgx v5.  I want to use pgx v5 because that handles marshaling of the INET type.  But when I try to import github.com/go-gorm/postgres it says the module is declaring itself as gorm.io/driver/postgres.  Is there a udpated version of gorm.io/driver/postgres that I could use to get the updated drive that is shown on github?